# Backslash dropped from string parameter and converted to its octal value in JSP rXesponse script

Tags: javascript, jspx

One of my PHP applcations is calling JSP method as shown below :
var reportWindow = window.open('DisplayView.aspx?viewId=' + viewId, '_blank', "height=700,width=900,left=20,top=20,scrollbars=auto,status=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
where viewID has values as below :

1. BANK\132ID
2. BANK\122ID
3. BANK\INT2616

We found that outcome of the JSPX is rendering viewID parameter in octal node values such as

1. BANK\132ID is converted to BANKZID
2. BANK\122ID is converted to BANKRID
3. BANK\IN2616 is converted to BANKINT2616 where only "" is dropped.

I feel there must be some way to prevent this conversion in JSPX and return the viewID value as is.
Any help is appreciated, thanks !